Is there any way to speed up nslcd LDAP server failover
TL;DR
Even with 2-second timeouts, nslcd "stalls" logins for 14 seconds before switching over to a secondary LDAP server.
Can I speed this up?
My nslcd config
uid nslcd
gid nslcd
uri ldaps://ldap01.myorg.net ldaps://ldap02.myorg.net
base dc=myorg,dc=net
binddn uid=ldapbind,ou=Users,dc=myorg,dc=net
bindpw my-pass
scope one
base group ou=Groups,dc=myorg,dc=net
base passwd ou=Users,dc=myorg,dc=net
base shadow ou=Users,dc=myorg,dc=net
bind_timelimit 2
timelimit 2
ssl on
tls_reqcert demand
tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
map    group  member           uniqueMember

My test method

Stop LDAP server on ldap01.myorg.net
Use SSH to log in to host

host uses nslcd with config above


See lengthy login delay

My host version

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
nslcd Ubuntu package version 0.9.11-1, upstream version 0.9.11

My host logs
Aug  7 19:45:17 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [6ab60f] <passwd="myuser"> ldap_result() failed: Can't contact LDAP server
Aug  7 19:45:19 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [6ab60f] <passwd="myuser"> failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://ldap01.myorg.net: Can't contact LDAP server: Connection timed out
Aug  7 19:45:19 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [6ab60f] <passwd="myuser"> connected to LDAP server ldaps://ldap02.myorg.net
Aug  7 19:45:19 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [6ab60f] <passwd="myuser"> (re)loading /etc/nsswitch.conf
Aug  7 19:45:19 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [0c57b1] <group=2345> connected to LDAP server ldaps://ldap01.myorg.net
Aug  7 19:45:19 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [0c57b1] <group=2345> ldap_result() failed: Can't contact LDAP server
Aug  7 19:45:21 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [0c57b1] <group=2345> failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://ldap01.myorg.net: Can't contact LDAP server: Connection timed out
Aug  7 19:45:21 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [0c57b1] <group=2345> connected to LDAP server ldaps://ldap02.myorg.net
Aug  7 19:45:22 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [0c50b3] <shadow="myuser"> connected to LDAP server ldaps://ldap01.myorg.net
Aug  7 19:45:22 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [0c50b3] <shadow="myuser"> ldap_result() failed: Can't contact LDAP server
Aug  7 19:45:24 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [0c50b3] <shadow="myuser"> failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://ldap01.myorg.net: Can't contact LDAP server: Connection timed out
Aug  7 19:45:24 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [0c50b3] <shadow="myuser"> connected to LDAP server ldaps://ldap02.myorg.net
Aug  7 19:45:24 myhost systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1234.
Aug  7 19:45:24 myhost systemd[1]: Starting User Runtime Directory /run/user/1234...
Aug  7 19:45:24 myhost systemd[1]: Finished User Runtime Directory /run/user/1234.
Aug  7 19:45:24 myhost systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1234...
Aug  7 19:45:24 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [32234b] <authz="myuser"> connected to LDAP server ldaps://ldap01.myorg.net
Aug  7 19:45:24 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [32234b] <authz="myuser"> ldap_result() failed: Can't contact LDAP server
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [32234b] <authz="myuser"> failed to bind to LDAP server ldaps://ldap01.myorg.net: Can't contact LDAP server: Connection timed out
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [32234b] <authz="myuser"> connected to LDAP server ldaps://ldap02.myorg.net
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Reached target Paths.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Reached target Timers.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Listening on debconf communication socket.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Reached target Sockets.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Reached target Basic System.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Reached target Main User Target.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1175418]: Startup finished in 120ms.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1234.
Aug  7 19:45:26 myhost systemd[1]: Started Session 15274 of user myuser.
Aug  7 19:46:34 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [801ee1] <authc="myuser"> connected to LDAP server ldaps://ldap01.myorg.net
Aug  7 19:46:34 myhost nslcd[1173796]: [801ee1] <authc="myuser"> ldap_result() failed: Can't contact LDAP server

